# Classe de inserir em PHP não funciona e não mostra erro

Tags: php, pdo, classes

Tenho o seguinte **código** em `php`:

```
<?php

class Users extends DB {

    private function verifyUser($email) {
        $select = self::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = '{$email}'");
        $select->execute();

        if ($select->rowCount() >= 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function insertUser($data = array()) {
        if ($this->verifyUsers($data[2])) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $insert = "INSERT INTO `users` (email) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            $stmt = self::conn()->prepare($insert);

            if ($stmt->execute($data)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ele não está funcionando, e também não mostra *erros*. Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Repare na sua `private function verifyUser($email){}`

O nome do método que você definiu está como **verifyUser**

E em `public function insertUser($data = array()){}` você está verificando um método que não existe, preste atenção, seu método é **verifyUser** você está usando **verifyUsers** com "**s**". Nunca vai funcionar mesmo.

Também troque:
`$insert = "INSERT INTO`users`(email) VALUES (?,?,?)";`

Por:
`$insert = "INSERT INTO`users`(email) VALUES (?)";`

Você não precisa de 3 **"?"**

Obs: Use o array `[2]` no `[0]`

Comment: Puts, nem tinha prestado atenção... e porque não mostra erro?

Comment: `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` Tens isto em teu código de conexão ?

Comment: Não, vou arrumar...

Comment: Tente usar também `try` e `catch`.

Comment: Deu certo... obrigado